# How to insert rowname if var name begins with certain string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, dplyr, dataset

Suppose that I have the following df:

```
library(dplyr)

glimpse(mydf)

Rows: 3,286
Columns: 741
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_GO_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_MG_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_MS_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_MT_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_PR_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_RS_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_US_IA_biz           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_US_IL_biz           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ gdd_90d_precip_GO_biz                 <dbl> 22.53283, 29.86229, 31.01503, 38…
$ gdd_90d_precip_MG_biz                 <dbl> 10.96422, 11.70888, 14.23489, 19…
$ gdd_90d_precip_MS_biz                 <dbl> 6.976152, 27.515620, 27.758262, …
$ gdd_90d_precip_MT_biz                 <dbl> 26.55052, 26.55052, 64.79208, 67…
...
```

I´m trying to insert a new column called `Group_Var` that show me based on the var name if is on climatic group, price group, and so on.

For example, how can I insert "climatic" using mutate on the new column `Group_Var` if the var names in `mydf` starts with "acc" ?

Comment: That's a nice glimpse of data, but we can't run anything on it. Please share a sample of data with `dput` instead so we can test things on it, say `dput(mydf[1:5, c(1, 2, 9, 10)]` for the first 5 rows of 4 selected columns. Also please show the desired output for the sample input and your `mutate` code so far. I don't see `Group_Var` and while some of your `mydf` names start with `"acc"`, some don't, so I'm not sure what you want...

Comment: @GregorThomas if you can see ``Group_Var`` showing the Climatic in each row if variable name starts with "acc" string I wouldn´t asked this question...

Comment: Okay, can you please show the desired result? I do not understand your goal.

Comment: My best guess for what you want: *if any column names in `mydf` start with `"acc"`, then add a new column to `mydf` named `Group_Var` that has the value `"climatic"` in every row.* Does that sound right?

Comment: If so, `if(any(df %>% names %>% startsWith("acc"))) df = mutate(df, Group_Var = "climatic")`

Answer (score 0):

My desired df is something like...

```
library(dplyr)

glimpse(mydf)

Rows: 3,286
Columns: 741
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_GO_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_MG_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_MS_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_MT_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_PR_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_RS_biz              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_US_IA_biz           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ acc_180d_gdd_diff_US_IL_biz           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ Group_Var                             <chr> "Climatic","Climatic","Climatic",...
$ gdd_90d_precip_GO_biz                 <dbl> 22.53283, 29.86229, 31.01503, 38…
$ gdd_90d_precip_MG_biz                 <dbl> 10.96422, 11.70888, 14.23489, 19…
$ gdd_90d_precip_MS_biz                 <dbl> 6.976152, 27.515620, 27.758262, …
$ gdd_90d_precip_MT_biz                 <dbl> 26.55052, 26.55052, 64.79208, 67…
```

Comment: You can click the "edit" button on your question to make changes to the question instead of putting this as an Answer

Comment: I can think better and solve my problem. Just used to pivot_longer and used inside mutate str_detect function...